# Cannot access useReducer value, returns empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks

I'm not sure what's going on here. I can't access the value that exists in my parent component's useReducer.

I have a function `vocabExtractor()` that dispatches sentences from a paragraph into an array in my reducer. It's been working just fine. However, when I try to access that element of state (through prop drilling) it comes back as an empty array.

In the example below, I call `vocabExtractor()`, it runs, and then on the next line I attempt to log `sentences` and it returns an `[]` empty array. I *know* `vocabExtractor()` is getting data to the reducer, but I'm running into (perhaps) some sort of async issue that I'm having a hard time figuring resolving.

Also, I left the `useReducer` dispatches out of the notes below, they are working as intended so the issue isn't there. It just spreads the array, adds in the data, and returns state. Standard stuff.

Any help would be appreciated.

> What the data looks like in the devtools, despite the console.log saying transcriptSentences is [ ]

[image]

***Parent Component***

```
const initialState = {
  activeStep: 0,
  notification: {
    format: "",
    message: "",
  },
  content: {
    lessonName: "",
    language: "",
    topics: [],
    format: "",
    file: "",
  },
  newWords: [],
  initialTranscript: "",
  modifiedTranscript: "",
  transcriptSentences: [],
};

const UploadPage = () => {
  const [selection, setSelection] = useState(0);
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState, init);

  return (
    <Content>
      <Main selection={selection}>
        <ReviewTranscript
          language={state.content.language}
          transcript={state.initialTranscript}
          sentences={state.transcriptSentences}.  <-- Prop in question
          lessonName={state.content.lessonName}
          dispatch={dispatch}
        />
        <AddVocab
          newWords={state.newWords}
          language={state.content.language}
          dispatch={dispatch}
        />
      </Main>
    </Content>
  );
};
```

***VocabExtractor()***

```
function vocabExtractor(transcript: string, dispatch: any) {
  const sentences = transcript.match(/([^\.!\?]+[\.!\?]+)|([^\.!\?]+$)/g);
  let vocabulary;
  if (sentences) {
    sentences.forEach((sentence) => {
      dispatch({ type: "ADD_SENTENCE", payload: sentence.trim() }); <-- Adds each sentence to state
    });

    vocabulary = sentences.map((sentence: string) => {
      return sentence
        .trim()
        .replace(/[.,\/#?!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g, "")
        .toLowerCase()
        .split(" ");
    });
  }

  const mergeDeDup = (arr: any): string[] => {
    return Array.from(new Set([].concat(...arr)));
  };
  return mergeDeDup(vocabulary);
}
```

***ReviewTranscript Component***

```
const ReviewTranscript = ({
  transcript,
  language,
  sentences,
  dispatch,
}: Props) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  const [modifiedTranscript, setModifiedTranscript] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    setModifiedTranscript(transcript);
  }, [transcript]);

  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    const trimmedTranscript = modifiedTranscript.trim();
    const uniqueWords = await vocabExtractor(trimmedTranscript, dispatch);
    
    console.log("sentences", sentences);  <-- sentences (passed in as a prop) logs []
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: My gut says that your `vocabExtractor()` is being fired on render or something. Can you give us a codesandbox to utilize?

Comment: @technicallynick Hey Nick, it is indeed running. I removed most of the unrelated code to make the content shorter above, but data is being passed into the `uniqueWords` variable. I'll explore the sandbox thing in a little bit, gonna try and clean up the rest of my code real quick and see if that helps.

Comment: I'd also be curious to know what your reducer function looks like for this.

Comment: @technicallynick hey you're in luck, I ran into an issue while trying to add types to it haha.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63984693/usereducer-hook-how-to-typecheck-the-action